# Trying to figure out the name of this hinge

Tags: repair

I want to repair a cupboard and it has a bit of a unique hinge, anyone know what the name might be?

[image]

Comment: https://duckduckgo.com/?q=euro+hinge&iax=images&ia=images

Answer (score 6):

They are called "Euro style hinges" because that is where they originally were developed for use on european box cabinets (compared to typical face frame cabinets). Nowadays they are common and the "usual" for cabinets. They come in a variety of opening angles. They also come with different base plates for inset, half overlay, and full overlay doors in box cabinets and also for mounting onto faceframe style cabinets.

You *may* be able to find these at a box store but their supply will be limited. Best bet would be to remove the hinge and the baseplate and take it to a cabinet maker or a cabinet supply shop where you could match up a proper replacement.

Comment: You will want to take a hinge off the cabinet (you'll probably need to take both off so the door isn't hanging on just one hinge), and take it to the store with you. There are a _ton_ of different specs that will need to be matched up to get the new one to fit where the old one was. A dedicated woodworkers supply store (Wood Crafters or Rockler, for example) or a local lumber yard would probably have an ample supply, the knowledge to match the hinge, and ability to order a replacement if they don't have the specific one in stock.

Answer (score 0):

They are called "soft closing hinges"

Check out the link

[image: hinge]

Source: [source](https://ebco.in/Soft-Close-Hinges)

Comment: Yes, but maybe to clarify: I need ones which seem to open beyond flat

Comment: @LucasKauffman I missed that in your OP. So you need more than 90 Dgr opening.

Comment: Woodworking supply shops sell every variety of hinge.  This one isn't special, it's a Euro cabinet hinge with opening of X degrees, whatever X is.   I sometimes go here for such things: https://www.rockler.com/hardware/cabinet-hardware/hinges.  The link in this answer also has ones with greater than 90 degree opening.

Comment: Not every "Euro style" hinge is a soft close hinge. I have _many_ in my house that aren't. I have some cabinets with a combination of 1 or 2 soft close and 1 or 2 not-soft close.

Comment: It’s absolutely not the case that “almost any” euro hinge will fit. This is terrible advice. Hinges have offset, overlay, opening degrees to name the critical ones.